# DATE Data Pivot Table day column and data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query to create a pivot table with the day as columns:

```
SELECT USERID,
CASE WHEN DATEPART(d,DATE) = 26 THEN sick END [26],
CASE WHEN DATEPART(d,DATE) = 27 THEN sick END [27],
CASE WHEN DATEPART(d,DATE) = 28 THEN sick END [28],
/* other days omitted */
CASE WHEN DATEPART(d,DATE) = 25 THEN sick END [25]
FROM tbl_Chktime
WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2017-12-26' AND '2017-12-28'  
AND USERID = '15831'
```

When I run this query this is my output:

```
USERID | 26   |  27  |   28   
15831   0.00    NULL    NULL        
15831   NULL    0.00    NULL        
15831   NULL    NULL    0.00
```

[Here is an image of the full output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcgqr.png)

I don't want those NULL values. Instead I prefer it to be shown as `0.00` similar to this:

```
USERID | 26   |   27  |  28   
15831   0.00    0.00    0.00
```

[Here is an image showing that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ks3Pd.png)

How do I need to change my SQL statement so it outputs 0.00 instead of null?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: `SELECT USERID,
max(CASE WHEN DATEPART(d,DATE) = 26 THEN sick END) [26],
max(CASE WHEN DATEPART(d,DATE) = 27 THEN sick END) [27],
max(CASE WHEN DATEPART(d,DATE) = 28 THEN sick END) [28],
max(CASE WHEN DATEPART(d,DATE) = 25 THEN sick END) [25]
FROM tbl_Chktime
WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2017-12-26' AND '2017-12-28'  
AND USERID = '15831' Group by USERID`

Comment: @rene - I voted to reopen , question is clear now

Comment: @Pரதீப் You'd better use a `PIVOT` statement. That can achieve the same result while being more concise, easier to understand and more efficient

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth - imo, conditional aggregation is much easier to understand. Also it is faster than `pivot` in larger tables http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/63681/

Comment: @Pரதீப் We differ in opinion on ease of understanding. I generally find that you should not repeat yourself often in an SQL statement, and conditional aggregation repeats itself a whole lot. Anyway, let's both answer. The question is clear, and might not be a full duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this easily if you stop pivoting manually, and let SQL server create the pivot for you:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT USERID, DATEPART(d,DATE) pivotHeading, sick
FROM tbl_Chktime
WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2017-12-26' AND '2017-12-28'  
AND USERID = '15831') src
PIVOT (Max(sick) FOR pivotHeading IN ([25], [26], [27], [28])) pt
```

That way, adding new dates doesn't extend the query length by much, and the statement is shorter.